# How can I enter main() without it looping login()

Tags: python

I am new in Python, I would like to ask how can make my code work.
in login() function, if the username and password are correct, log = True, then when go to main() function, log variable is not defined.

Then i found online where add log = login() in main() function, like this

```
def main():
    log = login()
    if log == True:
        identifier = loginChoice()
        if identifier == 1:
            customerMain()
        if identifier == 2:
            adminMain()
```

It works for that people, but for me, it goes into endless loop where it keeps calling login() function.

Below is my whole code

```
def loginChoice():
    print("\n","Login as:")
    print("1. Customer")
    print("2. Admin")
    choice =int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        login()
        return choice
    if choice == 2:
        login()
        return choice

def login():
    print("\n", "Login menu")
    user = input("Username: ")
    passw = input("Password: ")
    fhand = open("userpassword.txt", "r")
    for line in fhand.readlines():
        us, pw = line.strip().split("\t")
        if (user == us) and (passw == pw):
            log = True
            print("Login successful!")
            return True        
        else:
            print ("Wrong username/password")
            return False

def main():
    if log == True:
        identifier = loginChoice()
        if identifier == 1:
            customerMain()
        if identifier == 2:
            adminMain()
```

Thanks for helping me.

The screenshot of the login menu is in loop

[image: The screenshot of the login menu is in loop]

Comment: Why don't you just add ```else: loginChoice()```

Comment: If you have a `bool` variable, don't write `if x == True:`.   Instead, just write `if x:`.  Otherwise you're implying that it's *not* a `bool` variable, and that it may take on values other than `True` and `False`.  It makes no more sense than writing `if (((x == True) == True) == True) == True:`  None of the comparisons are necessary.

Comment: Please post your actual error message. Also your example don't seem to match. How is this executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code.this will works fine
but the customerMian() and adminMain() function not defined.

```py
def loginChoice():
    print("\n","Login as:")
    print("1. Customer")
    print("2. Admin")
    choice =int(input())
    return choice

def login():
    print("\n", "Login menu")
    user = input("Username: ")
    passw = input("Password: ")
    fhand = open("userpassword.txt", "r")
    for line in fhand.readlines():
        us,pw = line.strip().split("\t")
        if (user == us) and (passw == pw):
            print("Login successful!")
            return True        
        else:
            print ("Wrong username/password")
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = login()
    if log == True:
        identifier = loginChoice()
        if identifier == 1:
            customerMain()
        if identifier == 2:
            adminMain()
```

Comment: Much appreciate and it finally works!!
custMain() and adminMain() are my other functions

May I know how ``` if __name__ == '__main__': ``` works? Thank you so much!

Comment: `if name == 'main': ` means when run this python script.it will start here.if you script only contain functions.no code will run.